# How do I login if I never set a password?

Tags: pokemon-go

I signed up for Pokémon Go from Android with my Google account, but it did not prompt me to enter a password. I tried to log in using my iPhone later and it prompted me to enter my password. I tried using my Google password, but that is not working. Has anyone encountered the same issue? How do I resolve it?

Comment: Does the game have a separate app password? Check [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)

Comment: No...I tried to check but there is no separate app password

Comment: Are you sure you pressed Google login on your iphone or did you press Pokemon Trainer Club?

Answer (score 1):

On Android it did not prompt you because it will use the Google account linked to your Android device to log in to the game. If you want to use it on iPhone you will need to log in once so be sure you are using the same account as on your Android device (check under Account settings) and also be sure it is the correct password of course.